# Bazel tests fail on powerPC (ppc64le) architecture

Tags: linux, powerpc, rhel7, envoyproxy

I am on `rhel7.6 ppc64le`, trying to build a Istio-Envoy(release-1.3). I have devtoolset-7 installed on my system. The build of Istio-Envoy passes, however there are tests failures:

`ERROR: /envoy/test/server/BUILD:331:1: C++ compilation of rule` `'//test/server:filter_chain_benchmark_test' failed (Exit 1) gcc failed: error executing command /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' ... (remaining 490 argument(s) skipped)`
`INFO: Build completed, 14 tests FAILED, 4210 total actions`

I have changed certain sections of code to use power specific `LuaJIT` tar.
I am using the command `bazel test //test/...  --host_javabase=@local_jdk//:jdk --copt "-DENVOY_IGNORE_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI_ERROR=1"` to test the build.
Would like some help on understanding the same.

Answer (score 0):

As a former Red Hat employee for 9 years, I can tell you CentOS and RHEL share the same toolchain versions. CentOS supplies [glibc 2.17](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=71740) and apparently that is never going to change. The build of envoy may pass with devtoolset-7, however, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394286/gcc-woverloaded-virtual-error-on-powerpc-ppc64le), at least glibc 2.18 is required. Using glibc 2.17 will result in many failures in the test cases, even when using devtoolset-7 which is a more modern gcc compiler.